# Get mongodb documents with certain fields(projections) using Spring-Integration (annotations only)

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-integration, spring-data-mongodb

I am trying to get all documents from a mongodb collection which were modfied in last 5 minutes with certain fields only (say field1, field2, field3 and so on). How to write a LiteralExpression to get specific fields (projections)?

My current Literal Expression return documents containing all fields (_id is timestamp of document creation in my collection):

```
public String getLiteralExpression(){
        long innerBoundary = Instant.now().minus(5, ChronoUnit.MINUTES).toEpochMilli();
        long outerBoundary = Instant.now().toEpochMilli();
        String expression = new StringBuilder()
                .append("{'_id': {'$gt': ")
                .append(innerBoundary)
                .append(", '$lt' : ")
                .append(outerBoundary)
                .append("}}")
                .toString();
        return expression;
    }
}
```

Which is being invoked in InboundChannelAdapter as

```
@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(value = "pubSubChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedRate = "30000"))
public MessageSource<Object> DbReadingMessageSource() {

    Expression expression = new SpelExpressionParser().parseExpression("@myBean.getLiteralExpression()");

    MongoDbMessageSource messageSource = new MongoDbMessageSource(mongoTemplate, expression);
    messageSource.setCollectionNameExpression(new LiteralExpression(mongoTemplate.getCollectionName(MyEntity.class)));
    IntegrationFlows.from(messageSource);
    return messageSource;
}
```

Is there a way where I can just use MongoTemplate or MongoDbFactory instead of a LiteralExpression to fetch only certain fields (projection) in form of MongoDbMessageSource or any other format which can be fed to my pubsubChannel pipeline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a fact that the `expression` as a second `MongoDbMessageSource` argument can be resolved to the `org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query` object. So, it might not be just a plain *literal expression*. For your projection use-case you may write something like:

```
new BasicQuery([QUERY_STRING], [FIELD_STRING])
```

to be returned from your `@myBean.getLiteralExpression()`.

That `Query` API is pretty flexible and provides a lot of fluent hooks to be configured for the final MongoDB query. For example it has a `fields()` for `include/exclude` callbacks for specific fields you would like to be returned.

More info about `Query` API in the Spring Data MongoDB manual: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/2.1.5.RELEASE/reference/html/#mongodb-template-query

If you would like to use `MongoTemplate` directly instead, you need to write a custom code which should be called from the `MethodInvokingMessageSource` wrapper with the same `@InboundChannelAdapter` configuration. In that code you still need to build such a `Query` object to be able to delegate to the `MongoTemplate.find()`. That is exactly what is done in the `MongoDbMessageSource`.

Out of question: your `DbReadingMessageSource()` configuration is slightly wrong. You can't call `IntegrationFlows.from(messageSource);` from that bean definition. The `MongoDbMessageSource` must be configured as a separate `@Bean` and already without `@InboundChannelAdapter` annotation. The `IntegrationFlow` has to be another `@Bean` and there you really can use your `DbReadingMessageSource()` from that `from()`. But again: without `@InboundChannelAdapter`. See Reference Manual: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/#java-dsl-inbound-adapters